# USB Debugging in Brick phone

Tags: usb-debugging

Is it possible to enable USB Debugging in a bricked phone? my phone is not started so for Fastboot mode it requires usb debugging mode enable. but i didn't enable it. Is it possible?

Comment: You shouldn't need USB debugging for `fastboot`, as Android isn't even involved in the fastboot mode.

Answer (score -1):

Its impossible...

Everyone should enable debugging mode....
Otherwise if anything happens to your  phone its impossible to recover.

Comment: "If anything" is a broad term. USB Debugging would help as long as you can enter Android OS, fastboot doesn't need it enabled, and Recovery mode doesn't need it too. Also, for devices up to Android 4.2, having that option enabled can be troublesome since unlike 4.3+ debugging isn't authorized by user.

Comment: Additionally: how do you back that impossibility? Without giving some background, that's not really convincing. You should at least name the reasons. In this specific case, as Arch already pointed out, it would not even be necessary to enable USB debugging; so how does your answer help the OP?